# Resizable rectangles for nodes in D3 collapsible tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I modified the [collapsible tree example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) to use rectangles instead of circles.

https://plnkr.co/edit/UKUufJItPQqIKH8DBGLx?p=preview

My question is how to get the rectangle heights to resize themselves depending on the text of the nodes. If you'll notice that the top node has overflowing text while the size of the

I'm aware of .getBBox() and the [canonical wrap example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) but as I'm still newish to D3, I'm wondering how to bring it all together to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

**Canonical wrap**:

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

nodeHeight = 40, nodeWidth = 150;

nodeUpdate.selectAll("text").call(wrap,nodeWidth);

nodeUpdate.select('rect')
    .attr('rx', 6)
    .attr('ry', 6)
    .attr('y', -(nodeHeight / 2))
    .attr('width', nodeWidth)
    .attr('height', nodeHeight)
    .style('fill', function(d) { return d._children ? 'lightsteelblue' : '#fff'; });
```

**Using getBBox()**:

```
nodeUpdate.select('rect')
    .attr('rx', 6)
    .attr('ry', 6)
    .attr('y', -(nodeHeight / 2))
    .attr('width', function(d){
      var textElement = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text").node();
      var bbox = textElement.getBBox();
      var width = bbox.width;
      return width*2;
    })
    .attr('height', nodeHeight)
    .style('fill', function(d) { return d._children ? 'lightsteelblue' : '#fff'; });
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/KtSfKp8mpwnMXElfpC9r?p=preview

Comment: This is awesome! How would I modify this so that the width is fixed but the rectangle height resizes? I naively tried to swap 'width' with 'height' where applicable and unfortunately it wasn't that simple.